# Why isn't this JSP - Servlet code work?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've a package named classes which includes x.java and y.java.
x.java:

```
public class x{
private int a;
private int b;
private String c;
private String d;
private String e;
private String f;
//And the fields are encapsulated.
}
```

y.java:

```
public class y{
private List<x> xs;
private int k1;
private int k2;
private String k3;
private String k4;
//And the fields are encapsulated.
}
```

z.JSP:

```
<%
usecase y = new y();
request.getSession().setAttribute("yy", y);
%>
<form action="aaa?id=1" method="POST">
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="bbb"/>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="ccc"/>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="submit" name="ddd"/>
            </td>
        </form>
```

aaa.java (Servlet - inside the processRequest):

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        y yy = (y) request.getSession().getAttribute("yy");
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        x s = new x();
        s.setC(request.getParameter("bbb"));
        b.setD(request.getParameter("ccc"));

        if ("1".equals(id)) {
            s.setE("l");
        } else if ("2".equals(id)) {
            s.setE("k");
        }

        yy.getXs().add(s);
        response.sendRedirect("z.jsp");
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
```

Here's the code. when I watch it with a breakpoint everything goes well, variables get their values. But in this line: yy.getXs().add(s); there's an error and it doesn't redirect. Would you please help me?

**SOLUTION**: replace `private List<x> xs;` with `List<X> xs = new ArrayList<X>();`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I imported class.x and classes.y both in jsp and servlet.

Comment: It passes the line: response.sendRedirect("z.jsp"); Probably I get exception at the line: yy.getXs().add(s);. But have no idea why.

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Give meaningful names to your classes, fields, methods and JSPs. x, y, z, yy, k1, are just impossible to understand and maintain. And respect Java naming conventions: classes start with an upper-case latter.

Comment: INFO: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/qqq]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at z.processRequest(z.java:59)
 at z.doPost(z.java:97)

Comment: @JBNizet actually the names of the variables are not in English. That's why I changed them like that. I'm sure that there is not any syntax error and filename error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A NullPointerException, most of the time, means that you're dereferencing a null variable. I assume the line causing the exception (line 97 in `z.java`, as the stack trace indicates) is the following line:

```
yy.getXs().add(s);
```

Then it can mean two things:

1. `yy` is null
2. The list returned by `yy.getXs()` is null.

Use a debugger to identify the problem, or add logging traces in your code.

Comment: Thank you friend. I realized that I need to create the list with new in the class y.

Comment: isn't it enough to add List<x> xs = new List<x>(); instead of private List<x> xs; ?

Comment: it says implement all abstract methods

Comment: List is an interface. You must use a concrete implementation of the interface. For example: `List<X> xs = new ArrayList<X>();`