# how to create an object only if does not exists?

Tags: jsp, servlets

in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490288/why-isnt-this-jsp-servlet-code-work-solved)

code in z.JSP I want to create the object y only if it does not exists. I made a research but couldn't find it how.

Comment: if (whatever == null) { whatever == new TypeOfWhatever(); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
if(request.getSession().getAttribute("yy") == null) {
  usecase y = new y();
  request.getSession().setAttribute("yy", y);
}
```

which can be further simplified to:

```
if(session.getAttribute("yy") == null) {
  usecase y = new y();
  session.setAttribute("yy", y);
}
```

BTW read about [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Comment: But if its not null i still need to setAttribute("yy",y);. I need to fix it as well.
Sorry about the naming the variable names are not in English. That's why i rename them like that.

Comment: @kutluhanmetin: it's not about English but about using capital case where we used to. Please expand your question, looks like I don't understand it.